# Finding the lowest missing integer in a vector containing negative and positive values

Tags: c++, vectors

I'm writing an operation to find the lowest missing element of a vector, V = 1..N + 1. This has to be performed in \$O(N)\$ time complexity.

Solution One:

```
std::vector<int> A {3,4,1,4,6,7};

int main()
{
    int max_el = *std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end()); //Find max element
    std::vector<int> V(max_el);
    std::iota(V.begin(), V.end(), 1) //Populate V with all int's up to max element

    for(unsigned into i {0}; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
       int index = A[i] - 1;
       if(A[i] == V[index]) //Search V in O(1)
       {
         V[index] = max_el; //Set each to max_el, leaving the missing int 
       }
    }
    return *std::min_element(V.begin(), V.end()); //Find missing int as its the lowest (hasn't been set to max_el)
}

//Output: 2
```

This works completely fine. However, I'm now trying to get this to work with vector containing negative `int`s.

Solution Two:

My logic is to take the same approach, however 'weight' the indexes given the size of the vector and the number of negative `int`s in the vector:

```
std::vector<int> A {-1, -4, -2, 0, 3, 2, 1}
int main()
{
   int max_el = *std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
   int min_el = *std::min_element(A.begin(), A.end());
   int min_el_abs = abs(min_el); //Convert min element to absolute
   int total = min_el_abs + max_el;

   std::vector<int> V(total + 1);
   std::iota(V.begin(), V.end(), min_el);
   int index;

   //Find amount of negative int's
   int first_pos;
   for(unsigned int i {0}; i < A.size(); i++)
   {
      if(A[i] >= 0) {first_pos = i; break;}
   }

   for(unsigned int i {0}; i < A.size(); i++)
   {
      if(A[i] <= 0) //If negative
      {
          index = (A.size() - first_pos) - abs(A[i]);
       } else 
       {
          index = (A[i] + 1) + first_pos;
       }
       if(A[i] == V[index])
       {
          V[index] = 0;
       }
    } 
    return *std::min_element(V.begin(), V.end());
 } 

 //Output: -3
```

Solution Two fails to compare the values of the two vectors (A and V), as calculating the index with the above methods with a positive int doesn't work.

1. How can I get my Solution 2 to work with unordered vectors of negative `int`s?
2. How can I edit my Solution 2 to work with vectors of positive as well as vectors with negative `int`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strikes me as a fairly clumsy way to do the job. For example, you're using an `int` to represent what's essentially a single bit of information: is this number present or not?

I think I'd do something on this general order:

```
int find_missing(std::vector<int> const &in) {
    auto r = std::minmax_element(in.begin(), in.end());

    // Create a vector of the right size, with all elements set to false
    std::vector<bool> present(*(r.second) - *(r.first), false);

    // keep track of the smallest input for later use        
    auto lower = *(r.first);

    // mark each element in the input as being present
    for (auto i : in)
        present[i-lower] = true;

    // Find the position of the first element that's not present
    auto pos = std::find(present.begin(), present.end(), false);

    // Compute value from position
    return (pos - present.begin())+lower;
}
```

This uses `vector<bool>`, so it at least stands a decent chance of using only one bit to represent the one bit of information (is X present or not?)

It's still linear, and works for negative numbers. It gets rid of the "magic" numbers like using "max_el" as a signal instead of just a value.

If you want to, you could use a Boost dynamic_bitset instead of a `vector<bool>`, but in this case, `std::vector<bool>` (as defined in C++98/03) does exactly what we want<sup>1</sup>.

The major disadvantage of this method (though the code in the question has the same problem) is that this could waste quite a lot of memory if you happened to have an extremely sparse input. For example, an input like `-3,-2,-1, std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` would create an array of ~2 billion bools (assuming a 32-bit int), nearly all of which would be set to false, and never touched again.

Also note that in both cases, though the algorithm is linear, it's linear on the *range* of the inputs, not the actual number of inputs. For example, given an input of `{std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max()}`, we end up allocating and initializing 4 billion bools.

One other note: the code above portrays the general idea I'd use. If you might (for example) need to deal with inputs where the difference between the largest and smallest element will fit directly in the type of the element, you'll need to convert to either an unsigned type (carefully) or a larger type to ensure you can hold that difference correctly.

---

<sup>1. More recently the standard has been rewritten so it can still use only one bit per element, but can also use an entire `bool` per element if it prefers.</sup>